# SQL - Raise for every employee for average of their department salary

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know how to select average salary for every department:

```sql
select departments.dept_name, 0.1* round(avg(salary),2) as raise 
from employees 
  inner join departments using (dept_id) 
group by dept_name;
```

[image: Average salary of every department]

But i have to do this raise for every employee with a result of:

The result i need to achieve

[image: The result i need to achieve]

And I can't figure this out

The closest I can get is:

```sql
select surname, salary, 
       salary = (case when dept_id is null then 0 else round(avg(salary),2) end) as raise 
from employees 
group by dept_id, surname, salary 
order by surname;
```

with a result of:

[image: The result of my sql code]

Comment: what are you trying to perform? Are you trying to check whether the employee had been raised salary or how much salary they had been raised? (or employee average salary)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Do you want to `update` the employees table with the new salary? Or only select it?

Comment: Hello, i want to select it as is shown in the example, and in the second part is update the value of salary for this value of raise.

Comment: Regarding formatted text vs images: Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) for a great list of reasons why this is so important.